# bipartite projection without the intermediate bipartite graph

Tags: r, igraph, bipartite

I have a `data.frame` which describes a bipartite graph with a very large (millions) and a reasonably small (hundreds) independent sets.

I want to get the bipartite projection of the graph on the smaller independent set, but without first creating the large bipartite graph and especially the huge bipartite projection to the larger independent set. The reason for this limitation is an [`igraph` segfault](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1168894) and a RAM limitation (I have only 8GB RAM).

E.g., given

```
data.frame(beg=c("a","a","b","b","c","c"),
           end=c("1","2","1","2","1","2"),
           weight=1:6)
```

I want data frame

```
data.frame(beg=c("a","a","b"),
           end=c("b","c","c"),
           weight=c(1+3+2+4,1+5+2+6,3+5+4+6))
```

where weights of edges add up.

(in this example, `abc` is the "smaller" set and `12` is the "larger" one).

Comment: I wrote an answer and then I figured that I probably don't understand what you mean. by "without building the bipartite graph" you mean you want to avoid building its adjacency matrix? are you assuming that the graph is sparse?

Comment: @amit: my concerns are purely pragmatic: I want to avoid running out of RAM and crashing in `igraph` (see the edits).

Comment: How many nodes of each mode, and what is the expected density of the bipartite graph? If using sparse matrices doesn't do the trick (that's what igraph uses, as far as I know), then you might have some trouble doing this in R.

Comment: @ndoogan: the problem with igraph is the segfault

Comment: @ndoogan: bipartite graph of user ( 3,234,178 ) x publisher ( 100 ) 4,775,955 edges (density 1.476714 %)

Comment: OK. So segfault doesn't necessarily mean you ran out of memory, is that what you're saying? How about just trying this with plain sparse matrices? i.e. use the `Matrix` package with function `Matrix()`. As far as I understand, a sparse matrix is internally stored as something much smaller than the matrix object would be, like an edgelist.

Comment: Unfortunately, though, when I do `mat<-Matrix(rbinom(3234178*100,1,.01476714),3234178,100)` on an 8GB machine, the memory fills completely and R fails to complete the operation.

Comment: @ndoogan: of course one has to work with edge lists. I have something working, please take a look,

Comment: Just for the records, the problem with igraph is not the bug, that only happens because you supply the wrong vertex type vector: https://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph/+bug/1168894 The real problem is that igraph always creates both projections, and if one of them is huge, and the other is small, that is very inefficient. This will be fixed in the future: https://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph/+bug/1170075

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something which appears to do what I need (the key is to use [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) for fast join):

```
> library(igraph)
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.8.8  For help type: help("data.table")
> f <- data.frame(beg=c("a","a","b","b","c","c"),
                  end=c("1","2","1","2","1","2"),
                  count=1:6)
> f
   beg end count
1:   a   1     1
2:   b   1     3
3:   c   1     5
4:   a   2     2
5:   b   2     4
6:   c   2     6
> m <- f[f,allow.cartesian=TRUE]

> m
    end beg weight beg.1 weight.1
 1:   1   a      1     a        1
 2:   1   b      3     a        1
 3:   1   c      5     a        1
 4:   1   a      1     b        3
 5:   1   b      3     b        3
 6:   1   c      5     b        3
 7:   1   a      1     c        5
 8:   1   b      3     c        5
 9:   1   c      5     c        5
10:   2   a      2     a        2
11:   2   b      4     a        2
12:   2   c      6     a        2
13:   2   a      2     b        4
14:   2   b      4     b        4
15:   2   c      6     b        4
16:   2   a      2     c        6
17:   2   b      4     c        6
18:   2   c      6     c        6
> v <- m$beg == m$beg.1
> m <- f[f,allow.cartesian=TRUE]
> v <- m$beg == m$beg.1
> m$end <- NULL
> m$weight <- (m$count + m$count.1)/2
> m$count <- NULL
> m$count.1 <- NULL
> m
    beg beg.1 weight
 1:   a     a      1
 2:   b     a      2
 3:   c     a      3
 4:   a     b      2
 5:   b     b      3
 6:   c     b      4
 7:   a     c      3
 8:   b     c      4
 9:   c     c      5
10:   a     a      2
11:   b     a      3
12:   c     a      4
13:   a     b      3
14:   b     b      4
15:   c     b      5
16:   a     c      4
17:   b     c      5
18:   c     c      6
> ve <- data.table(vertex=m$beg[v], weight=m$weight[v], key="vertex")
> ve <- ve[, list(count = .N, weight = sum(weight)), by = "vertex"]
> ve
   vertex count weight
1:      a     2      3
2:      b     2      7
3:      c     2     11
> g1 <- graph.data.frame(m[!v,], vertices=ve, directed=FALSE)
> g1 <- simplify(g1, edge.attr.comb="sum")
> V(g1)$weight
[1]  3  7 11
> E(g1)$weight
[1] 10 14 18
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I'd do it (assuming your edge is in df, and the "small" set is in the beginning of an edge)

For every pair of nodes in the small set I'll use the following:

```
do.pair = function(x,y) {
     tmp = intersect(df$end[df$beg==x],df$end[df$beg==y])
     res = sum(df$weight[(df$beg %in% c(x,y)) & (df$end %in% tmp)])
     return(res)
}
```

now, I'd create the list of pairs in your favorite way (you can use exapnd.grid or outer) and then use the relevant apply function with the above, here I just do a simple nested loop, not extremely efficient but simple to read.

```
g.small = unique(df$beg)
n = length(g.small)
res = list()
cnt=0
for (i in 1:(n-1)) {
    for (j in (i+1):n) {
       cnt = cnt+1
       res[[cnt]] = list(beg=g.small[i],end=g.small[j],weight=do.pair(g.small[i],g.small[j]))
    }
}

do.call(rbind,res)
```